# Is there a way to get "updated by" for "git.pullrequest.updated" web hook?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

See title.

Context: My bot is sometimes change a PR in response for updating PR, a need a reliable way to filter out own changes. Is there some more reliable way than parsing "detailedMessage.text" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/events?toc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Ftoc.json&bc=%2Fazure%2Fdevops%2Fmarketplace-extensibility%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&view=azure-devops#git.pullrequest.updated) I don't think that this is possible.

You may try to create a feature request on developer community, but it won't be provided soon (probably).

You're only way is `detailed message`.

Please notice that you don't have even notification type, so you don't know if reviewers were changed ro it is sth different. It can be distinguished also only byt detaled message or message.

Comment: Thanks, opened https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1021191/api-add-updatedby-field-in-web-hook-payload.html